# SaveToAlbum function is not working in my Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-camera

Hey guys I am working on a iOS app using Xamarin that open's the camera and takes a picture and then saves it to the camera roll, however when I hit the use photo button the app crashes

here's what VS2012 says is causing the crash:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here's my code:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;

namespace ToolBelt.iOS
{
    partial class CameraView : UIViewController

    {
        public CameraView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {       
        }



        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();


            //UIPopoverController popover = new UIPopoverController (ctrl);

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }




        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            if (imageView.Image == null)
            {
                UIImagePickerController picker = new UIImagePickerController();

                picker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
                picker.Delegate = this;
                PresentViewController(picker, true, null);
            }
        }

        [Export("imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:")]
        public void FinishedPickingImage(UIKit.UIImagePickerController picker, UIKit.UIImage image, Foundation.NSDictionary editingInfo)
        {
            var someImage = UIImage.FromFile("someImage.jpg");
            someImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum((pic, error) =>
                {
                    var o = pic as UIImage;
                    Console.WriteLine("error:" + error);
                });
            DismissViewController(true, null);

        }
    }


}
```

what am I doing wrong?

any help would be amazing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: var someImage = UIImage.FromFile("someImage.jpg"); <- does that file exist???? for what are you showing the image picker if you try to use a file local to your bundle?

Comment: @Gusman Thanks for the reply i do not have a image called someImage.jpg in the project any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, you must use the image returned by the picker, in your case is the UIImage passed to your function named "image".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a hardcoded image which doesn't exist instead of using the user's picked image.

Change your code to this:

```
    [Export("imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:")]
    public void FinishedPickingImage(UIKit.UIImagePickerController picker, UIKit.UIImage image, Foundation.NSDictionary editingInfo)
    {
        image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((pic, error) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error:" + error);
            });
        DismissViewController(true, null);

    }
```

Comment: one other issue is after i take the picture the camera doesn't go away it keeps re-opening any ideas on how to close it?